# Removing a string from a string array in C ( i.e. removing an item from an item from a 2D array)

Tags: arrays, c, string

So I have an array of strings which contains duplicates. My overall goal is to remove the duplicates and resize the array accordingly. The best way I've of going about this so far was using the memmove() function.

My current test approach is to loop through the array and scan every item. If a string is encountered more than once then I would to overwrite the duplicate with next item in the list using memmove(). Every item in the list would also be shifted up one place in the array using memmove() too. I would then resize the entire array to remove the empty memory locations at the end of the array.

I have declared the array as so:

```
char source[43][20];
```

The array is just a list of cities(I've included just the first 6 for demonstration):

```
York
Leeds
Liverpool
Manchester
Reading
Oxford
```

I managed to overwrite the first element with the second element with the following code:

```
memmove(&(source[0][0]), &(source[1][0]), strlen(source[1]) * sizeof(char));
```

Giving this output:

```
Leeds
Leeds
Liverpool
Manchester
Reading
Oxford
```

but when I try overwriting the third element over the second element with this code:

```
memmove(&(source[1][0]), &(source[2][0]), strlen(source[2]) * sizeof(char));
```

I get this output:

```
Leeds
Liverpooφu
Liverpool
Manchester
Reading
Oxford
```

As you can see, Liverpool is not working as intended. Currently I don't know how to resize the array either at the moment so I would be grateful for any ideas on that. Appreciate any help guys :).

Comment: `strlen(source[1]) * sizeof(char));` but what about copying the zero terminating character? Just `strcpy` then, no need for `memmove`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do the copy, you're not copying over the terminating null byte.  This means that whatever garbage that happens to be after what was copied will be read as if its part of the string.

Since you have fixed size array elements, just copy over the entire subarray:

```
memcpy(source[0], source[1], sizeof(source[0]));
```

And if you want to move multiple elements:

```
memmove(source[0], source[1], sizeof(source[0]) * num_to_move);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about the zero terminating character when copying strings. You need `strlen(...) + 1` to copy a string including zero terminating character.

`sizeof(char)` can be omitted - `char` is always 1 byte, `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

No need to use `memmove` here, assuming `strlen(source[2]) + 1 < 20`, then `source[1], source[1] + strlen(source[2])` and `source[2], source[2] + strlen(source[2])]` are disjoing memory regions. Just `memcpy` then. But for that matter, just `strcpy` the strings.

```
strcpy(source[0], stource[1]);
strcpy(source[1], stource[2]);
// etc...
```

If you don't care about extra bytes beeing copied, you could move all the strings up in one go, like:

```
memmove(&source[0], &source[1], sizeof(source) - 1 * sizeof(*source));
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you cannot resize arrays. In order to be able to use `realloc` you can do something like this:

```
char (*source)[20] = malloc(sizeof *source * 43);
```

That will give you a pointer to array of 20 char, and then you allocate memory for 43 such arrays. This can be reallocated later. Like this:

```
char (*source)[20] tmp = realloc(source, sizeof *source * size);
if(tmp)
    source = tmp;
else
    // Handle error
```

Note that `char (*source)[20]` is completely different from `char *source[20]`. The latter is an array of 20 pointers.

Also note that `sizeof` can be a bit tricky. The above works, but it would have to be modified if you used `char **source` instead of `char (*source)[20]`.

For completeness, even though other have mentioned it, your problem is that you're not copying the `\0` character. The simplest solution is to use `strcpy`, but `strncpy` is safer.

```
strncpy(source[0], source[1], 20);
```